# Make a border go around entire window causes vertical scroll bar to show?

Tags: css, border

With my search, I have found that the following code should make a border go around whole browser window.

Almost ...

Even with zero content within `<body>`, a vertical scroll bar shows:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;

    margin: 0px;

    border: solid darkgreen;
}
```

I desperately need a rescue team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your `body CSS`.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;    
    margin: 0px;    
    border: solid darkgreen;
    box-sizing: border-box; // add this line
}
```

Read more about `box-sizing` from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: YES!! Does this have something to do with margin collapse?

Comment: I guess no, [Check this out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)